# How to toggle between two widgets in yii

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have two widgets in a view one of those is a yii CGridView widget and another is a calender widget

Basically both the calender and the grid does the same task of displaying the events but in different styles.

What i need is i place a button on the top and by clicking on that  my widgets will toggle

Suppose currently gridview is being displayed if i click the button then the calender view will be displayed and  the other way round

Please help me how to accomplish this without using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do:

```
<span id="grid">Grid</span><span id="calendar" style="display:none;">Calendar</span>
```

`<button id="tglBtn">Toggle</button>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById('tglBtn');
var grid = document.getElementById('grid');
var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');

btn.addEventListener('click', toggle);
function toggle() {
    grid.style.display = (grid.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    calendar.style.display = (calendar.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}</script>
```

What you do basically is, hide one of the widgets using css and then attach a click event listener to the toggle button that handles the switching.

Hope that helps :D